# How to extract all compressed files in directory and subdirectories and rename with the prefix of the parent directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have a list of `*.tar.gz` files named `A01.tar.gz... A10.tar.gz`. Each file contains a directory named `Files` and this directory contains 3 .gz files named `1.txt.gz, 2.csv.gz and 3.tsv.gz`.
I would like to extract all the gz files into one directory and rename them with the prefix of their parent/parent directory. ex: `A01_1.txt, A10_.1.txt`. How can I do that with bash?

Edit: I have found the solution

```
for filename in *.tar.gz; do
  tar xvzf "$filename" --one-top-level; #the file will have the same name as the tar.gz file
    for F in "${filename%%.*}"/*/*.gz; do 
     STEM=$(basename "${F}" .gz) #get the base names of the target .gz files
     gunzip -c "${F}" > ./"${filename%%.*}${STEM}" #redirects the output of gunzip to a file which will have the prefix of the grand parent file+ the base name of the target .gz file.
    done
  done #all the files will be extracted to the working directory and will have the prefix of their original tag.gz file.
```

Thanks for all who answered.

Comment: Use "dynamic programming" principle - split complicated task into groups of smallest possible little tasks. So: 1. Iterate over `*.tar.gz` files. 2. For each file, extract it to some directory. 3. Iterate over `files/{1,2,3}.*.gz` files extracted from previous point. 4. Extract those files. 5. Rename those files. 6. Repeat. With what exactly are you having problem with?

Comment: Please see original post for what I have tried.

Comment: Your first problem is `tar xvf ... > ...` because `tar` doesn't work like that - it unpacks to the name of the directory in the tarball, i.e. `Files` in your case. You can't redirect the unpacking with `>` like that.

Comment: Indeed, so now I did this for the first step `for filename in *.tar.gz;
  do tar xvzf "$filename" --one-top-level;
  done`. But I dont know how I can keep the $filename variable so I can append it as a prefix to all extracted gz files in the second step.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than putting code updates in comments where they are hard to read.